# XML Xpath Failing on getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddProduct>
<auth><id>vendor123</id><auth_code>abc123</auth_code></auth>
</AddProduct>
```

What am I doing wrong to get : Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()

```
$xml = $_GET['xmlRequest'];
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$auth = $xpath->query('*/auth');
$id = $auth->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$code = $auth->getElementsByTagName('auth_code')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: If I may make a recommendation, never use `@` to suppress error warnings when you're debugging.

Comment: Try changing your XPath to `//auth` or `/AddProduct/auth`

Comment: Actually, upon further review, `DOMXpath` doesn't have `getElementsByTagName` property, however `DOMDocument` does have it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for your recommendation!  It led me to the real problem, which was that the XML was riddled with backslashes from copying and pasting from emacs.  Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the data (in the XML you posted) you want using XPath only:

```
$id = $xpath->query('//auth/id')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$code = $xpath->query('//auth/auth_code')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

You are also calling `getElementsByTagName()` on `$auth` (`DOMXPath`), as @Ohgodwhy pointed out in the comments, which is causing the error. If you want to use it, you should call it on `$dom`.

Your XPath expression returns the `auth` child of the *current* (context) node. Unless your XML file is different, it's clearer to use one of:

```
/*/auth           # returns auth nodes two levels below root
/AddProduct/auth  # returns auth nodes in below /AddProduct
//auth            # returns all auth nodes
```

Comment: If you replace query() with evaluate(), you can fetch the value directly by casting the result list in Xpath. `$id = $xpath->evaluate('string(//auth/id)');`

Comment: Thanks!  This works well.  Awarding because this is what I'm using in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with after reviewing php's documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php, https://www.php.net/domxpath)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$id = $dom->getElementsByTagName("id")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$code = $dom->getElementsByTagName("auth_code")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

As helderdarocha and Ohgodwhy pointed out, the getElementByTagName is a DOMDocument method not a DOMXPath method. I like helderdarocha's solution that only uses XPath, the solution I posted accomplishes the same thing but only uses the DOMDocument.